# Is it possible to email a panel with css being used

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, email

I have a panel on my website which is filled with all kinds of data from labels to repeaters etc...

I have gotten it down to printing just the panel I want with

```
        Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
        Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
        Dim html As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)
        pnlLabOrderPrintEmail.RenderControl(html)

        Dim str As String = SW.ToString()

        Return str
```

Which gives me the bare bones of the panel. My panel on the page has styles on it, making it much prettier. However, when the email is sent, the css is not attached of course.

Is there a way to send the panel as is? With the styles carried over?

I have seen

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates/Order.htm"))
body = reader.ReadToEnd

'Claim/Lab Order Reference Number
body = body.Replace("{ClaimReference}", lblReferenceNo.Text)
```

which is a separate .htm page with placeholders which you replace your content with and send that .htm page off.
Isn't there a quicker way, than replacing the placeholders and sending the .htm page? Could I not just copy my panel into the body of the email? Could I perhaps take an image of the panel and send that as an embedded image on the email body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the set .htm page and overwrote the placeholders with what I wanted. 
At least this way I can use styles to change the .htm page